# Object not moving on grid?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a pseudo-snake game using a 25x25 grid. I'm using a pretty simple tactic using DOM gridArea. Here is my code:

```
let snakex = 0; // x of snake on grid.
let snakey = 0; // y of snake on grid.
let temp = 0; // Doesn't have any function, I just prefer to have a temp variable with no use in places that have no function.

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    const key = event.key;
    switch(key) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            if (snakex - 1 == 0) { 
                temp -= 1;
            } // If the fact that moving left will make the snake leave the grid, it will not move and the function won't do anything.
            else {
                snakex -= 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = "'" + snakey + "/" + snakex + "'";    
            } // Move the snake to the left, while updating the x of the snake on the grid.
            break;

        case "ArrowRight":
            if (snakex + 1 == 26) {
                temp += 1;
            }
            else {
                snakex += 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = "'" + snakey + "/" + snakex + "'"; 
            }
            break;

        case "ArrowUp":
            if (snakey - 1 == 0) {
                temp -= 1;
            }
            else {
                snakey -= 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = "'" + snakey + "/" + snakex + "'"; 
            }
            break;

        case "ArrowDown":
            if (snakey + 1 == 26) {
                temp += 1;
            }
            else {
                snakey += 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = "'" + snakey + "/" + snakex + "'"; 
            }
            break;
    }
    if (onFood()) {
        moveFood();
    } // Different functions, don't have to do with the question.
}
```

The snake gridArea does not update on the button pressed. I don't seem to know what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to replace your

`snake.style.gridArea = "'" + snakey + "/" + snakex + "'";`

by

`snake.style.gridArea = snakey + "/" + snakex;`

the extra quote you're adding are problematics

(for some reason the snippets doesn't take the firsts input so move a little in all directions)

```js
let snakex = 0; // x of snake on grid.
let snakey = 0; // y of snake on grid.
let temp = 0; // Doesn't have any function, I just prefer to have a temp variable with no use in places that have no function.

let snake = document.getElementById("snake")
let onFood = () => false

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    const key = event.key;
    switch(key) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            if (snakex - 1 == 0) { 
                temp -= 1;
            } // If the fact that moving left will make the snake leave the grid, it will not move and the function won't do anything.
            else {
                snakex -= 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = snakey + "/" + snakex;    
            } // Move the snake to the left, while updating the x of the snake on the grid.
            break;

        case "ArrowRight":
            if (snakex + 1 == 26) {
                temp += 1;
            }
            else {
                snakex += 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = snakey + "/" + snakex 
            }
            break;

        case "ArrowUp":
            if (snakey - 1 == 0) {
                temp -= 1;
            }
            else {
                snakey -= 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = snakey + "/" + snakex
            }
            break;

        case "ArrowDown":
            if (snakey + 1 == 26) {
                temp += 1;
            }
            else {
                snakey += 1;
                snake.style.gridArea = snakey + "/" + snakex
            }
            break;
    }
    if (onFood()) {
        moveFood();
    } // Different functions, don't have to do with the question.
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#snake {
  grid-area: 0/0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="snake"/>
```